# Why in Using Visual Studio >> SSAS as DirectQuey Mode when i need to deploy any data the data Disappear

Tags: ssas

Why in Using Visual Studio >> SSAS as DirectQuey Mode
when i need to deploy any data
the data Disappear
And it just appears tne Metadata[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBWiR.png)
i  need to know how to solve this problem
i  need to know how to solve this problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the steps you made to the question so that others may be able to reproduce your issue.